# OpenedX stanford theming customization

Tags: python, django, edx

I am new to Django/edX. I am using the stanford edX theme (https://github.com/Stanford-Online/edx-theme) for openedX full stack deployment. I want to change "Free courses from Stanford for anyone, anywhere, anytime" that appears on homepage. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The template you need is located in `edx-platform/lms/templates/index.html`.

It uses mako templating and looks like this,

```
<h1>${_("Free courses from <strong>{university_name}</strong>").format(university_name="Stanford")}</h1>
              <h2>${_("For anyone, anywhere, anytime")}</h2>
```